# Problem with CallLog

Tags: android

I am trying to add durations of all calls in current month. I am comparing the month of mobile time with month of call to add calls in current month. But dates of calls is returning 1. I am tried to get full dates and it is ever 1.1.1970.(Yes, I checked date of calls and its right 4.4.2011)

Source code:

```
    DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    long currentDate = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    String currentDatess = date.format(currentDate);
    int d1 = Integer.valueOf(currentDatess.toString());
    Log.d(TAG,"Value od d1: " + d1); **->> it is returning right value(now 4)**

    Cursor cCall = getContentResolver().query(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null");

    while(cCall.moveToNext()){
                CallsDuration = cCall.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
                CallDateFull = cCall.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE);
                calendar.setTimeInMillis(CallDateFull);
                String datess  = date.format(calendar.getTime());
                datesss = Integer.valueOf(datess.toString());
                String callDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(CallDateFull); **-> only for test,it is ever returning 1.1.1970**
                Log.d(TAG, "Test: " + callDate);

                totalTimeInInt = totalTimeInInt + CallsDuration; **--> Total duration time of all calls**


                Log.d(TAG, "Date: " + datesss); --> this is  returning 1(1.1.1970)
                if (d1 == datesss){
                    CallsInMonth = CallsInMonth + CallsDuration;
                }

                }

            TotalTime = String.valueOf(totalTimeInInt);
            CallInMonthString = String.valueOf(CallsInMonth);


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are formatting the index of column:

```
CallDateFull = cCall.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE);
```

You must get the long value of the cursor:

```
CallDateFull = cCall.getLong(cCall.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE));
```